# Was my computer hacked by Minecraft/Craftbukkit Initscript?

Tags: wireless, networking, security

I was playing around in Terminal, I 'mis-clicked' (havent yet configured trackpad, very jumpy cursor) while trying to run nano.

What happened next kind of threw me for a loop. Here is what printed inside my LXTerminal.. (I am ucd...)

```
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ sudo nano do.ws> > >For list information, ...
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ [ADMIN] CraftBukkit Initscript for CentOS/Fedora/Ubuntu | Bukkit ...
[ADMIN]: command not found
Bukkit: command not found
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ forums.bukkit.org › Home › Forums › Bukkit › Bukkit Tools
forums.bukkit.org: command not found
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ 30 posts - 6 authors - Feb 19, 2012 30: command not found
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ This is an initscript to run a Minecraft or CraftBukkit server on ... CraftBukkit (pid 9037) is running. .... ERROR: Process ID list syntax error.
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ Getting the process ID in a shell script
```

What could that be? My cursor is very jumpy, like extremely, and it jumped when this happened. I have no idea what Minecraft or Bukkit is?

I would appreciate it vastly if you gave me some clues. 
also I have a user called 'irc' in my faillog -a output. Is that normal?

Comment: oh, a clue... how fascinating that the very part that is absurdly large because I cant control formatting well, contains the clue. "Getting the process ID in a shell script" was a webpage that my chromium browser was viewing at the time this happened. So it looks like data from my web browser leaked into terminal. Still wanting feedback though!!!

Comment: It looks like you accidentally pasted something into your terminal. Minecraft is a computer game.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you pasted some text into the terminal by accident. Since the text you copied contained carriage returns, commands were executed. I see no reason to think anything bad is happening here.

It looks like the text you pasted was, or was very similar to:

```
> > >For list information, ...
[ADMIN] CraftBukkit Initscript for CentOS/Fedora/Ubuntu | Bukkit ...
forums.bukkit.org › Home › Forums › Bukkit › Bukkit Tools
30 posts - 6 authors - Feb 19, 2012 30
This is an initscript to run a Minecraft or CraftBukkit server on ... CraftBukkit (pid 9037) is running. .... ERROR: Process ID list syntax error.
```

The output error messages you got are *mostly* consistent with this input. To the extent to which they are not, I suspect some characters just didn't copy and paste correctly, or that there is a discrepancy between what appeared in your Terminal window and what you were able to put into your post. I also improved the formatting in your post but perhaps I made a mistake; that could also account for the discrepancy.

I am not worried. Unless you have *additional* information to suggest a problem, I wouldn't recommend you be concerned either.

#### Here's what all your error messages mean:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

The `>` operator redirects the output of the command on the left to the file specified on the right. But you have more than one of these, separated from each other with spaces (so you're not making the `>>` operator, for instance.) That is a syntax error. `>` can only be followed by a valid filename.

```
[ADMIN]: command not found
```

You ran a string as a command that contained the `|` operator. This runs the command to the left of it, and sends (pipes) its output to be the input of the command on the right. The first word of the command on the left was `[ADMIN]`, so it was interpreted as the name of the command and everything following it was interpreted as command-line arguments to that command.

But there is no `[ADMIN]` command--no shell builtin, shell alias, shell function, or program by that name. Therefore, that command was not found and could not be run.

```
Bukkit: command not found
```

This is the same situation, just on the right-hand side of the `|` operator.

```
forums.bukkit.org: command not found
```

You ran a command where the first word (i.e., before the first space) was `forums.bukkit.org`, like `[ADMIN]` and `Bukkit`, there is no command called `forums.bukkit.org`.

```
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ 30 posts - 6 authors - Feb 19, 2012 30: command not found
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here. The error message appears on a line where a command was entered, which is unusual, though it sometimes happens when a program runs and produces strange output (output without the expected carriage returns, or output produced after the program has already returned control of the terminal to the shell that invoked it.

But it's not unexpected to see another `command not found` error, from text that isn't commands randomly being pasted into the terminal.

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The line you ran contained a leading parenthesis (and a closing one, too, but the shell never got far enough to parse that) under circumstances that didn't make sense to the shell. Parentheses are used to group commands, and the syntax you gave is inconsistent with that use.

```
ucd@ucd-uc:~$ Getting the process ID in a shell script
```

This is not output at all. This is just the last line you pasted. Since it's the last line, no carriage return was pasted. So this is just the text you pasted, on a prompt. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get rid of it.

Comment: I was thinking the user had selected that in a web browser, and accidentally middle-clicked. But it is unlikely that he would have been reading about how to run a Minecraft server if he didn't know what Minecraft is!

Comment: I think someone else on that uses this computer might now what it is... _shrug_